# Node.js serial port Access denied how to fix it

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I have a following error.
it works okay when the computer on but if i shutdown the computer and turn on again, the com port is exist but the node.js told me "(node:5244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Opening COM3: Access denied"

If I unplug the com port and plug it and it works fine.
how to solve this problem?

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs= require('fs');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3",{baudRate:9600},false);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var ct=0;




serialPort.open(function(){
    console.log('connected...');
  serialPort.on('data',function(data){
      console.log('data received: ' +data);
      data=data+"";
      io.emit('Fromjs',data);
    });
  });


server.listen(3200, function() {
  console.log('Socket IO server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Looks like it's been long. Do you remember how you fixed this? Thanks!